# How to filter search by language Jupyter Notebook

Tags: github-api

I need to filter my search by Jupyter notebook

Im using python library "pygithub" for searching repositories on github.com. My code is next:

```
from github import Github
g = Github("login", "password")
repositories = g.search_repositories(query='Self organizing map language:Python')
for repo in repositories:
   do smth
```

It works ok with language:python, but how to be with language Jupyter Notebook?
I have used:

```
language:JupyterNotebook
language:Jupyter_Notebook
language:Jupyter
language:Notebook
```

Nothing works...

Answer (score 1):

that answer is language:jupyter-notebook